# Android : instance variables and get view items in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm beggining with android development and I don't know where to instanciate my ArrayList and the better way to access views:

```
public class LevelMenu extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener {

(...)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_menu_1, container, false);
    listeView = new ArrayList<>();
    listeView.add(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_menu_1, container, false));
    listeView.add(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_menu_2, container, false));
    listeView.add(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_menu_3, container, false));
    listeView.add(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_level_menu_4, container, false));
    // how to change imageView
    view.findViewById(R.id.next).setOnTouchListener(this);
    view.findViewById(R.id.previous).setOnTouchListener(this);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

is it the right place and the right way to do it ? I'm a little bit lost with all that views, activities, inflater etc that you can't access anywhere...
There is lots of tutorial on internet but I ve not found any which give the right ways to code in a tidy way.

thanks for reading

Comment: You should declare your array as a global variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
My array is global but is initialized in this method. The question is for initilazation not declaration.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct place to initialice all your objects.

Comment: Ok thanks :) Android is so muddled.